# read_csv() & EOF character in string cause parsing issue

Tags: python

I am trying to read in 50 csv files from a zip file but keep getting

CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: EOF inside string starting at line 166
I know there is an error with reading a particular string within the data and can fix in manually but dont want to have to extract all csv files manually to fix each one.

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('C:\Users\Austen\Anaconda\cs109_final\CA34.zip') as zf:
   for name in zf.namelist():
      container[name] = pd.read_csv(zf.open(name))
```

The problem I found is that there is a single ; in each csv file towards the end of the file. How would I ignore that?

With reference from:

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5500

Tried to add

```
    container[name] = pd.read_csv(zf.open(name),skipfooter=4)
```

But I get 'unexpected end of data'

Comment: I seem to recall someone using read_table to get around this.  Worth a shot imo

Comment: I get the same error when I use pd.read_table

Comment: If the `;` character occurs in a predictable or detectable location, you could first manually read in each archive member file, clean it up, and then pass the sanitized version on the `pd.read_csv()`. If the uncompressed csv member files aren't too big, you could do all this processing in memory very quickly.

Comment: It is always in the third to last line, but the size of each file varies. is there a way to search the file delete that line and then read the updated file in a dataframe? I don't want to use the last 3 lines in the dataframe anyway

Comment: Are there possibly other `;` characters in the files you'd want to preserve? Also it's unclear what a `;` has to do with an EOF character.

Comment: It is just that one towards the end of the file. How would I read the files in and delete the last 3 lines and then save it as a dataframe?

Comment: To ignore the last 3 lines of a file, you'd first have to determine how many lines were in the file, and the read it a second time from the beginning and stop when you get to the third-from-the-end line.

Comment: @AustenNovis I just tried to recreate this and couldn't.  I'm using 0.15.1.  What version are you using?

Comment: Using '0.12.0'. Dataframes are from the pandas library. Is the best way to get length by summing every row?

Comment: @AustenNovis Ok, upgrading might help.  Also, I just read some of your other comments regarding deleting the last 3 lines.  You can use the skipfooter argument in read_csv()    skipfooter : int, default 0
Number of lines at bottom of file to skip (Unsupported with engine=’c’)

Comment: with skipfooter I get the error 'unexpected end of data'

Comment: yikes..  I see you went through the trouble of finding the row count.  Instead of skiprows maybe try nrows.    nrows : int, default None
Number of rows of file to read. Useful for reading pieces of large files

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the pandas library. However I have an idea about how to clean up the files without have to read through each one of them twice. The result could be written to a temp file, which could then be passed on to `pd.read_csv()`. LMK if you think something like that would an acceptable solution and I'll give it a shot and post an answer.

Comment: Some parting thoughts on this  1) try using the nrows argument.  2) copy one of those CSVs from the zip file and place in a plain old folder and try read_csv() again.  Maybe the compression with the zip file is causing problems with read_csv().  3) Upgrade Pandas.  You are a few versions behind.

Comment: Cool!  Wow, that was a weird one.  That skipfooter error might be worth filing.  I wonder if you had any CSVs that were less than 4 lines?

Answer (score 6):

Would adding an option to read_csv fix the problem?  I had a similar problem and it was fixed by adding the option quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE

For example:

```
df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, header = None, delimiter="\t", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, encoding='utf-8')
```

The second comment in this discussion talks about why:
https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5500

Comment: Note: You will have to `import csv` before

Answer (score 2):

Passing engine="python" solves the issue.

Reference:[Most frequent errors](http://www.shanelynn.ie/pandas-csv-error-error-tokenizing-data-c-error-eof-inside-string-starting-at-line/)